# How to use nesting defines from objc/c in swift?

Tags: c, swift, objective-c, xcode

I have C header with some defines from a library vendor. Defines look likes:

```swift
#define TEST_DEFINE_1 0x12340000
#define TEST_DEFINE_2 TEST_DEFINE_1
    
#define TEST_USE_DEFINE_1 (TEST_DEFINE_1| 0x0001)
#define TEST_USE_DEFINE_2 (TEST_DEFINE_2| 0x0001)
```

I want to use these defines in my swift code, so i added Bridging Header:

```swift
#ifndef Bridging_Header_h
#define Bridging_Header_h

#include "defines.h"

#endif /* Bridging_Header_h */
```

And use them:

```swift
print(TEST_DEFINE_1)
print(TEST_DEFINE_2)
print(TEST_USE_DEFINE_1)

// This line causes error "Cannot find 'TEST_USE_DEFINE_2' in scope"
print(TEST_USE_DEFINE_2)
```

So i can't use nested defines with arithmetic.

Is there problem in swift/xcode? Or am i doing it wrong?

There is repo with minimal example: https://github.com/aatriff/define_test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this documentation for [working with C macros in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/using_imported_c_macros_in_swift).

Here are the relevant parts:

> Swift automatically imports simple, constant-like macros, declared
> with the #define directive, as global constants. Macros are imported
> when they use literals for string, floating-point, or integer values,
> or use operators like +, -, >, and == between literals or previously
> defined macros.

> **C macros that are more complex than simple constant definitions have
> no counterpart in Swift.** You use complex macros in C and Objective-C
> to avoid type-checking constraints or to avoid retyping large amounts
> of boilerplate code. However, macros can make debugging and
> refactoring difficult. In Swift, you can use functions and generics to
> achieve the same results without any compromises.

---

**EDIT**
Here is a workaround that I've used before:

In Bridging_Header.h add a wrapper function

```c
    int exposeTestUseDefine2()
    {
        return TEST_USE_DEFINE_2;
    }
```

main.swift

```swift
    print(exposeTestUseDefine2())
```

Comment: "Macros are imported when they use [...] operators like +, -, >, and == between literals or *previously defined macros*." I'm not sure if `TEST_DEFINE_2` counts as a "previously defined macro". If it does, then this would be a bug...

Comment: "Macros are imported when they use literals for string, floating-point, or integer values, or use operators like +, -, >, and == between literals or previously defined macros." - may be i make wrong interpretation, but TEST_USE_DEFINE_2 uses operators on integer and previously defined TEST_DEFINE_2, so should be imported. It is not imported even if i replace "|" with "+".

Comment: However, if i change my header to this one:
```swift
#define TEST_DEFINE_1 0x12340000
#define TEST_DEFINE_2 (TEST_DEFINE_1 + 0)

#define TEST_USE_DEFINE_1 (TEST_DEFINE_1| 0x0001)
#define TEST_USE_DEFINE_2 (TEST_DEFINE_2| 0x0001)
```
it works.

Looks like doc is strict: macros can't rely on another macros directly, only on macros with arithmetic